# Como puedo agregar un texbox que se crea en tiempo de ejecución dentro de una celda en específico de un DataGrid usando visual basic y WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-basic

estoy trabajando con visual basic y WPF 2022, y mi problema es que necesito insertar un textbox que se crea al momento de ejecución al dar click en un botón y se agrege dentro de un DataGrid en una celda en específico. Mi código es el siguiente:

Private Sub ButtonHijo2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles botone.Click

```
Dim text As New TextBox
With text
    .Height = 50
    .Width = 50
    .Background = Brushes.Blue
    .Foreground = Brushes.White
    .Focus()
    .TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
    .Text = contar
End With
```

DataGrid.children.add(text)

End Sub

Solo me lo agrega en la primera celda del Datagrid y no puedo colocarlo en una en específico, alguien me podría ayudar por favor.